# Right join JPA query fails to get exact ouput

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem with this query in JPA

Employee table

`id,....,location_id (id 1,2,3,4 assigned to location id 1)`

EmployeeMaster table

```
id,.....,date, employee_id(employee_id 1 and 2 having records in this table)
```

JPA query

```
select me,ms from EmployeeMaster ms right join ms.employee me where ms.date between ?2 and ?3 and me.location.id = ?4
```

Output

```
employeeMaster,employee1
employeeMaster,employee2
```

Because only two employees having records in EmployeeMaster table between dates

I want the output be like

```
employeeMaster,employee1
employeeMaster,employee2
null,employee3
null,employee4
```

Please help me to solve this

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

instead of retrieving employeeMaster retrieve employee and you will get your result.

Comment: Still getting the same result.

Comment: how did you implement my suggestion?

Comment: Select me from EmployeeMaster ms right join ms.employee me where ms.date between ?2 and ?3 and me.location.id = ?4

Comment: @AshokReddy that is expected when you are using right join , use left join instead